# Как запустить сервер с сайтами на разных PHP?

Tags: php, apache

Имеется хостинг с установленным Apache 2.2 и версией PHP 5.4. На нём висят несколько сайтов. Локально начал разработку сайта на PHP 7, использую OpenServer. Вопрос, как залить сайт на другой версии php на хостинг? Нормально ли разворачивать отдельный Open Server на хостинге под мой проект?

Comment: open server  - это пакет под виндоуз, Хостинг у вас скорее всего на юниксах. Спросите у хостера, поддерживают ли они php7

Comment: openserver это окружение для разработки и не более. так что "разворачивать опенсервер на хостинге" это весьма странное предложение. Как сказано выше, обратитесь в суппорт хостера. тут вам ничем не помогут с данным вопросом.

Comment: @splash58 хостинг у нашей компании свой и он на Windows Server 2016 и там стоит Apache 2.2 и PHP 5.4

Comment: @teran я знаю, что такое open server, я не нашёл как выразиться. хостинг как я написал в комментарии выше

Comment: @splash58 вопрос не в поддержке, вопрос в том, рационально ли так делать? можно ли на один сервер Apache поставить несколько php, например, для разных сайтов?

Comment: Сконфигурить разный php для разных сайтов реально

Comment: @splash58 ну вот в этом и вопрос. подскажете как?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=apache%20diff%20php%20for%20each%20site&clid=2261451&banerid=0899050204%3ASW-488adf45b4c5&win=280&lr=219

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, конечно, но я сюда пришёл именно потому что не нашёл ничего путного в поисковике и ожидаю более конкретного ответа здесь

Comment: я уже просто не помню, сто лет назад на денвере налаживал. больше было не надо. Может, кто подскажет

Comment: @GrizzlyK Плохо искали, видимо. Вот сразу выпадает инструкция, подробней некуда http://network.lamantinclub.com/64-neskolko-versij-php-na-odnom-apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мы у себя используем с Windows Server 2008 XAMPP.
Вот тут можете скачать любую версию: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/

Тут инструкция как сделать виртуальные хосты в нем https://pacificsky.ru/web-server/windows-web-server/xampp/178-xampp-dobavlenie-domena-i-virtualnogo-hosta.html

После этого сможете указать нужную версию PHP для каждого домена.

Answer (score 0):

На хостинг OpenServer вряд ли поставить... На VPS - наверное можно.

Вообще в публичном сервере обычно используют хостинг-панели. В хостинга-панелях есть возможность выбирать версии PHP для отдельного сайта.

Control Web Panel например и дешево, и нафарширована нормально, и поддержка.